# Why the code returning an array with a single letter instead of whole name?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Learning Destructuring assignment in Javascript and when trying to have an array in object destructuring, just first letter return to console, why it’s happening?

```js
function splitter(name) {
  const [fName, lName] = name.split(" ");
  return { fName, lName };
}

const {fName: [firstWord],lName} = splitter("John Doe");

console.log(splitter("John Doe"));
console.log({fName: [firstWord],lName});

console.log(firstWord);
console.log(lName);
```

[image: An image of code showing an object containing elements for fname and lname as in: object { fName: "John", lName: "Doe"}]

Comment: Because `fName` is a string. A string is basically an array of characters. So passing `[firstWord]` is the same as saying: *"Give me the first element of the array"* (i.e. the first character).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*trying to have an array in object destructuring*". What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because `splitter` returns you `fName` and `lName`, each of them is a word, string, which is an array of characters.

When you restructure `fName` to an array, it gives you the first letter in the array.

If you will add more args to the array you will get the rest of the letters.

To fix your issue just don't restructure into an array.

```js
function splitter(name) {
  const [fName, lName] = name.split(" ");
  return { fName, lName };
}

const {fName: [ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4],lName} = splitter("John Doe");

console.log({fName: [ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4],lName});

const {fName: [char1, ...restOfChars]} = splitter("John Doe");
console.log(char1);
console.log(restOfChars);

const {fName: wholeWord} = splitter("John Doe");
console.log(wholeWord);
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's first take the simple case, where you are just destructuring the array

```js
function splitter(name) {
  const [fName, lName] = name.split(' ');
  return { fName, lName };
}

const { fName, lName } = splitter('John Doe');
console.log(fName); // John
```

> Remember the `strings` are iterable in JS

```js
const str = 'John';

for (let c of str) {  // For-of can only be used in iterables
  console.log(c);
}
```

So when you do

```
const { fName: [firstWord], lName } = splitter('John Doe');
```

then this means you are also destructuring from the `fName` string, which will result in the `firstChar` as

So the above  is exactly same as:

```
const { fName, lName } = splitter('John Doe');
const [firstChar] = fName;
console.log(firstChar);
```

```js
function splitter(name) {
  const [fName, lName] = name.split(' ');
  return { fName, lName };
}

const { fName, lName } = splitter('John Doe');
const [firstChar] = fName;
console.log(firstChar);
```

Comment: good explanation, but I've a question could you please tell us why you use `equal` `=` in destructuring `{ fName = [firstWord],` instead of `colon` `:` like that `{fName: [firstWord],`

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi that was a typo, I should have used `:` instead of `=`